# Two layouts to be loaded for single activity

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

I'm having two `layout.xml` files. I need to load either one of the XML in a activity. Say initially i will be loading an activity using `SetContentView` and if a `button` click is done then i have to load another `layout.xml` file.

How can i do this?

This change will be frequently done in the activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you have `layout1.xml` and `layout2.xml`

Change between them using

```
setContentView(layout1);

setContentView(layout2);
```

**Careful**

> If you have buttons,textviews... that you reference using `findViewById()`, you must re-reference them again after calling `setContentView()`

Answer (score 0):

call

```
setContentView(layout1);
```

and in your onClick() method, call

```
setContentView(layout2);
```